# get Parameter from Route laravel to route laravel with angular js

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-5, pagination

I have two route like below code (Second route for angular js pagination):

```
Route::get('history/{fixassid}',function (){
        return view('assetmanagement.history.pchistory');
    });
Route::get('/api/v1/pchists/','HistoryController@getpc_his');
```

My Angular js

```
var app = angular.module('angtable', ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination'])
    .constant('API_URL', 'http://testing/mypro/public/api/v1/');
app.controller('pchistory', function ($scope, $http, API_URL) {
    $scope.currentPage=1;
    $scope.itemsPerPage=10;

    $scope.sizes = [ {code: 0, name: '5'}, {code: 1, name: '10'}, {code: 2, name: '15'}, {code: 3, name: '20'}, {code: 4, name: '30'} ];
    $scope.update = function() {
        //console.log($scope.item.code, $scope.item.name)
        $scope.itemsPerPage= $scope.item.name;
    }

    //retrieve employees listing from API
    $http.get(API_URL + "pchists")
        .success(function (response) {
            $scope.pchists = response;
        });

    $scope.sort = function (keyname) {
        $scope.sortKey = keyname;   //set the sortKey to the param passed
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse; //if true make it false and vice versa
    }
});
```

When i click on blade temaplate

```
<a href="{{url('history/'.$get_history_pc->fixass_id)}}">( View History )</a>
```

I want to pass fixassid to controller HistoryController and function getpc_his how can?

Comment: are you using `angularjs` or `angular`? Please update the tag accordingly

Comment: @Aravind: Angular

Comment: so you should be sending the value in the `[routerLink]` attribute of `<a>`

Comment: @Aravind: Can you show me your answer?

Comment: Like this `<a [routerLink]="['/hero', hero.id]">`

Comment: from where you call `/api/v1/pchists/` is it from the `assetmanagement.history.pchistory` view ?

Comment: @Aravind: can you look at my update question again

Comment: @Maraboc: this route is from my angular please look at my update question

Comment: @TheRock you are using `angularjs`

Comment: @Aravind : Oops sorry guy i am new with angular and angular js

Comment: @Aravind can you help me?